# Check if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n^2+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\right|$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

This is the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n^2+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\right|$$

We can drop the absolute value, because;
$$\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n^2+1)} > \frac{1}{2}$$

I've tried using inequalities below to form comparison tests, but to no avail.

$$\frac{n}{n+1} < \ln(n+1) < n$$
$$\frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{\ln(n^2+1)} < \frac{n^2+1}{n^2}$$

I also tried d'Alembert's ratio test, but it resulted in limit of 1, which is inconclusive. I have no clues on how to approach this.

Comment: Welcome! Thank you for providing context with your question. I have edited the title to something more specific. Please use more descriptive titles in future.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: $$\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n^2+1)}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2\log(n+1)-\log(n^2+1)}{2\log(n^2+1)}=\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{2n}{n^2+1}\right)}{2\log(n^2+1)}$$ This gives the numerator is a $$\sim\frac{2n}{n^2+1}\sim\frac2n.$$ The denominator is $\sim 4\log n.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One has

\begin{align*}
\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n^2+1)} -\frac{1}{2} &= \frac{\ln(n)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\ln(n^2)+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)} -\frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{\ln(n)+ \frac{1}{n}+ o\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)}{2\ln(n)+  o\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)} -\frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{ \frac{1}{n} + o\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)}{2\ln(n) + o\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)} \sim \frac{1}{2n\ln(n)}
\end{align*}

This is the general term of a divergent series, hence by comparison, the original series diverges.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \begin{align}  a_n&=\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n^2+1)}-\frac{1}{2}\\&=\frac{2\log(n+1)-\log(n^2+1)}{2\log(n^2+1)}\\&=\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{2n}{n^2+1}\right)}{2\log(n^2+1)} \end{align} $$ This gives the numerator is $$\sim\frac{2n}{n^2+1}\sim\frac2n.$$ The denominator is $\sim 4\log n.$

So: $a_n\cdot n\log n\to \frac{1}2.$

So you get that your terms are bounded below by $\frac1{4n\log n}$ with $n$ large. The integral test shows $\sum\frac1{4n\log n}$ diverges.